# Date format to string in ddmmyyyy

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, date

So I am working on an existing workbook so I cannot change the layout unfortunately. In the first sheet, a function automatically returns today's date in the "yyyymmdd" format. On another sheet, that date needs to be filled into 8 different cells (like on an offical document such as a pdf). So for example, 20000101 would need to be |0|1|0|1|2|0|0|0|, with each bar representing a new cell.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is a screenshot of the file. It's an official document so I can't change the layout unfortunately.

Comment: do you want **ddmmyyyy** or **mmddyyyy** ???

Comment: Good point, it should be ddmmyyyy

Comment: @TomBird - You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some typical code:

```
Sub fillinthedata()
    Dim  sh As Worksheet, s As String
    Set sh = Sheets("another sheet")

    s = "20201225"
    s2 = Right(s, 2) & Mid(s, 5, 2) & Left(s, 4)

    For i = 1 To 8
        sh.Range("A1").Offset(0, i - 1) = Mid(s2, i, 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```